# Using Partial type for overrides in TypeScript 2.4

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I have a function that gives me a fixture that should conform to a `Person` interface:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  email: string
  age?: number
}

function makePerson(override: Partial<Person> = {}): Person {
  return {
    name: 'Jim',
    email: 'jim@example.com,
    age: 24,
    ...override,
  }
}
```

In TypeScript 2.3 this would work fine; I could call the function something like this to override a certain key:

```
const myPerson = makePerson({name: 'Bob'})
// {
//   name: 'Bob',
//   email: 'jim@example.com,
//   age: 24,
// }
```

But, having updated to 2.4, the compiler now gives an error like this:

```
Type '{ name: string | undefined; email: string | undefined; age: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I can see why it's doing this - in JavaScript it would be possible to override any of the keys in the object by passing in object with one of more keys set to `undefined`, which would override the default and result in the function returning an object not conforming to `Person`. This is because omitting a key is different to setting it `undefined`.

Is there a way to achieve what used to work whilst retaining the maximum type safety?

Comment: Perhaps `Overwrite` could help you here, see [#12215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215) for implementations by nirendy and ahejlsberg.

Comment: That looks like a nice feature suggestion but I don't think it addresses this issue. The problem is TS2.4 being stricter about its implementation of `Partial` and how it interprets `undefined` which could be an omission of a key or a key actually set to `undefined`. 2.3 is less fussy and assumes that if the key in the override is `undefined` it's been omitted from and won't overwrite the default.

Comment: Sorry, I see now. I was able to make it work now by disabling `strictNullChecks`. May not be ideal, but it's something. `Overwrite` fortunately isn't a feature request anymore; if you add a definition it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the best answer, but you could get around it by avoiding the object spread, and setting each individual field.

```
function makePerson(override: Partial<Person> = {}): Person {
  return {
    name: override.name !== undefined ? override.name : 'Jim',
    email: override.email !== undefined ? override.email : 'jim@example.com',
    age: override.age !== undefined ? override.age : 24
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's an option. Maybe to define a `applyOverrides` function that takes a generic to do this. But not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This answer at least *looks* like theory only - however it works.

View the type as a set of properties, and you'd like to be able to call `makePerson` with any given subset of these properties - the *power set* of all properties. The type can be expressed:

```
type Person_Powerset = 
    {} |
    {email: string} | { name: string }  | { age: number} |
    {name: string, email: string} | {name: string, age: number} | {email: string, age: number} |
    {name: string, email: string, age: number};
```

I don't know whether TypeScript is expressive enough at the type level to allow constructing this type, e.g. like in `Powerset<Person>`.